# Pico/Mini Projector for Windows Phone?

Tags: camera

I want to project my app which uses camera on my wall. So, does Windows Phone have Pico projector?

Answer (score 2):

No, as of now there is no way to project from the phone. When you see Microsoft reps doing it they are using a special build of the OS.

At the moment there is no way for us to project from the phone.